# Run visual basic in vs code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to run vb console app in vscode, the .net interactive window only supports C# and F#

Comment: Are you asking how to compile and run the code, or show your code using vb.net formatting and syntax?  If compile and run the code, pretty much the same as any other .net toolkit, heaps of documentation around.  If formatting/syntax highlighting.  In the bottom right, there is Select Language mode options where you can set visual basic (might be other ways, but I know that one)

Comment: [Visual Studio Community edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) is free software.

Comment: @Hursey I think the question is about the VSCode equivalent of the Immediate window.

Comment: Wanted to install vb.net on multiple computers at once, problem is it was taking time so wanted to find an extension that allows me to run and debug vb apps in vscode.